# Cake App with jQuery Ajax doesn't work on remote server :(

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've a problem with my Cake App.

My action code is following:

```
public function event($year, $month) {
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
            return new CakeResponse(array('body'=> json_encode($this->Event->getMessages($year, $month))));
        else
            $this->set('event', $this->Event->getMessages($year, $month));
}
```

Further I've a second action, which is empty method:

```
public function tester(){}
```

and associated View (tester.ctp)

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>    
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var url = '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'event', '2013', '4'));?>';
            $.get(url, function(data){ 
               data = $.parseJSON(data);
               for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                   $('#result').append(data[i].date + ' ' + data[i].message + '<br />');
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Problem is following. My app works perfectly on my local server, but doesn't work on remote.
Frustrating is that, when I swap Cake on a some controller written in pure PHP then problem doesn't exist and all works perfectly on local and remote servers.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' means?? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I mean that my (js) script can't show any result because variable data in callback function is empty.

Comment: I've got any error, but in $.ajax.error callback function value of response.responseText contains my data from server. How is it possible? Why exists error which doesn't exists?

Comment: Ok, I found it. There is an internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at _serialize in the CakePHP manual http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

You can send a request to /events/event/2013/4.json and by using _serialize retrieve a json object back, be sure to add Router::parseExtensions('json'); to your routes file.

```
public function event($year, $month) {
    $this->set('event', $this->Event->getMessages($year, $month));
    $this->set('_serialize', array('event'));
}
```

This way you don't need to detect if it's ajax or not.